# Unable to post login data via Python requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to to scrape some information about items I borrowed at my local library, but I fail to get past the login page.

I inspected the site in Firefox and I think my POST request is the same that I see there. Yet I only receive error 500 when I attempt to query in Python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.buecherhallen.de/login.html'

with requests.Session() as session:
    get_result = requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    login_root = BeautifulSoup(get_result.text, 'lxml')
    login_form = login_root.find('form', {'id': 'tl_login'})

    payload = {
        'FORM_SUBMIT': login_form.find('input', {'name':'FORM_SUBMIT'})['value'],
        'REQUEST_TOKEN': login_form.find('input', {'name': 'REQUEST_TOKEN'})['value'],
        'username': 'myname',
        'password': 'mypass'
    }
    post_result = requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    print(post_result)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Firefox shows the following headers, but adding them to the post (I removed the length) changes nothing.

```
POST /login.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.buecherhallen.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.buecherhallen.de/login.html
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 111
Origin: https://www.buecherhallen.de
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _pk_id.2.888c=e27b9a9bbadfdc74.1585264176.24.1589919329.1589919311.; PHPSESSID=45dbcf287720b23a3e0f3e621be26ee3; _pk_ses.2.888c=1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

Comment: Do you have headers?

Comment: @NerdicSapo I added the headers to the question, nothing is different if I use them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found the problem now!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely you are getting your request blocked, trying `print(get_result.content)` and see if that HTML is the same as the HTML of the page when you visit it manually. If they are different try setting the user-agent as the same as the request you sent manually.

Comment: The content looks very similar. Of course the request token is different. Faking a different user agent did not work.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was calling the requests from the `requests` module instead of from the session.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.buecherhallen.de/login.html'

with requests.Session() as session:
    get_result = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
    login_root = BeautifulSoup(get_result.text, 'lxml')
    login_form = login_root.find('form', {'id': 'tl_login'})

    payload = {
        'FORM_SUBMIT': login_form.find('input', {'name':'FORM_SUBMIT'})['value'],
        'REQUEST_TOKEN': login_form.find('input', {'name': 'REQUEST_TOKEN'})['value'],
        'username': 'myname',
        'password': 'mypass'
    }

    post_result = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    print(post_result)
```

If I actually use the session a neccessary cookie is stored during GET and then used during POST. Otherwise it is just ignored.